# amount of memory allocated when double is converted to string

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

i have data structure i am passing this from server to client using data contract.
the data structure is

```
class datatransfer
{
    double m_value1;

    double m_value2;

    double m_value3;
};
```

in the client i want to write into file.

- The idea is to convert the values of the data transfer into string using string builder
  than transfer the string to the client.

or

- send the data structure and write the file using stream writer

which is the best approach? converting to string or send the datastructure and write to the file?

Reason for the question: to avoid the generation of string.

double size is 8 bytes. If i convert it to string what will be the size allocated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends entirely on how you format the `String` representation of the `Double`. There is no pre-defined sizing guideline.

For example:

```
var myDouble = 5.183498029834092834D;

var shortString = myDouble.ToString("#.00"); // 5.18, uses 8 bytes
var longerString = myDouble.ToString("#.0000000"); // 5.1834980 18 bytes
```

*Note that the sizes are the result of a `Char` being 2 bytes on my system.*

What you're really trying to do is called [*serialization*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx).  There's a number of ways to do this. The simplest of which may be to just decorate your class with the [`[Serializable]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[Serializable]
public class datatransfer {
    double m_value1;
    double m_value2;
    double m_value3;
}
```

You'll need to make your member variables `public`, or provide publicly accessible properties for setting the member variables. Otherwise they will not be serialized using this approach.

Comment: It's not necessary to qualify "char being two bytes" as "on your system".  It's in the spec that way; it's not dependent on the system.

Answer (score 1):

The size of a double when converted to string depends on the number itself and the encoding of the string.

Just as example, assuming ANSI encoding, the number **1** will need 1 byte, the number **1.123** will need 5 bytes. Moreover if you transmit that as text you need to consider more bytes used as delimiters (for example, using a space, you'll need N - 1 extra bytes). You should always transfer data in binary (if possible but it may depend on the type of connection you have and the protocol you have to use).

As a general rule you should think that binary data is smaller (then faster to transfer) but it's not easy to debug and you may have problems with a firewall. Text data is larger, verbose, you have to validate them on client side (your structure, XML for example, may be corrupted) and then slower to transfer. Big advantages are it's more easy to debug and whatever connection/protocol you may have usually you can transfer text (but don't forget you can transfer binary data encoded as text).

So this is not a definitive answer, what kind of data transfer method/framework/protocol you're using? A WCF service? .NET Remoting? Custom TCP/IP connection? If data structure is not too big you may find that binary serialization is a very good solution

Comment: Careful when giving sizing estimates. I assumed the same thing - that one `char` is equal to one `byte`. On my machine the .NET framework uses **2** bytes for a single `char`. Check `sizeof(Char)` for yourself.

Comment: @Yuck Adriano has covered the two-byte character issue by "assuming ANSI encoding", in which each character *is* one byte.